# Скрыть в трей программу на C++/CLR (Windows Forms)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

`Form1->Hide();` пишет,что ему нужен идентификатор.

Распишите пожалуйста подробно, как в Visual Studio в конструкторе форм сделать, чтобы на кнопку программа скрывалась в трей, в трее, если нажать правой кнопкой мыши, была лишь 1 кнопка "Главное меню" `contextmenustrip1` и `notifyicon1` я сделял

Comment: В каком конструкторе форм? Вы уверены, что это не Windows Forms и C++/CLI?

Comment: c++/clr windows forms у меня

Comment: NotifyIcon - Указывает компонент, который создает значок в области уведомлений.https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

Comment: Используйте ссылку на форму, а не название класса. То есть `this->Hide()`, если это в коде самой формы, или `form->Hide()`, где `form` - _ссылка_,

Comment: Если не получается скрыть форму, то лучше оставить только эту проблему, а после решения попробовать разобраться с остальным (самостоятельно или в новых вопросах). Приведите [исполняемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы Вас легче было понять.